# Color surface by variable with plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

Using the `volcano` data, I would like to color the surface of the volcano by another variable, which is a matrix, `MatrixForColor`, of the same size as `volcano` and it only contains 1s and 2s (is binary). For `MatrixForColor = 1` and `MatrixForColor = 2` I want to color blue and red, respectively.

Inspired from [Formatting of persp3d plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258787/formatting-of-persp3d-plot), I managed to achieve this using `persp3d` from `rgl` package as following:

```
library(rgl)    
color = c("blue", "red")
type  = MatrixForColor
persp3d(volcano, theta=50, phi=25, expand=0.75, col=color[type],
        ticktype="detailed", xlab="", ylab="", zlab="", axes=TRUE)
```

and obtained this figure:

[image]

I also tried to achieve this with `plotly` (adapting after the response from [plotly - different colours for different surfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150158/plotly-different-colours-for-different-surfaces)) as following:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(colors = c('blue', 'red')) %>%
  add_surface(z = volcano,
              opacity = 0.8,
              surfacecolor=MatrixForColor,
              cauto=F,
              cmax=1,
              cmin=0
  )
```

but I get this figure:

[image]

which is not what I want, since it's not colored as red and blue after `MatrixForColor`.

Any has any idea how to do this with `plotly`?

Comment: Can you also include `MatrixForColor` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set correct values for `cmin` and `cmax`:

```
library(plotly)

MatrixForColor <- matrix(1, nrow = nrow(volcano), ncol = ncol(volcano))
MatrixForColor[, 1:30] <- 2

plot_ly(colors = c('blue', 'red')) %>%
  add_surface(z = volcano,
              opacity = 0.8,
              surfacecolor = MatrixForColor,
              cauto=F,
              cmax=max(MatrixForColor),
              cmin=min(MatrixForColor)
  )
```

[image]