# How to add dates on axis with persp3D from plot3D package?

Tags: r, date, plot, 3d

I'm trying to make a persp3D plot but I can't figure out how to add dates on the x-axis. It only lets me change the lable of the axis, but I haven't found a way to get certain values on the axis.

```
persp3D(x= (1:iNumberOfDays),y= (1:iNumberOfVariables) ,z= zValue, xlab = "Time")
```

I also have a date vector `vDates` with `iNumberOfDays` elements which I would like to use on the x-axis as on any regular 2d lineplot or something.

Comment: You can use `persp()` way of setting labels, described here: http://entrenchant.blogspot.com/2014/03/custom-tick-labels-in-r-perspective.html
and here
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-July/109936.html
and here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252702/3d-plot-in-r-better-visible-surface

Answer (score 1):

You can try to pass `vDates` to the `x` argument and set `ticktype = "detailed"` as follows:

```
persp3D(x=vDates, y=1:iNumberOfVariables, z=zValue, xlab="Time", ticktype="detailed")
```