# R Layers of Color in a Multivariate Plot

Tags: r, charts, colors

How do we make different layers of colours to better see a Multivariate Function in R? I would like to check whether the function is Quasi-Concave and Quasi-Convex, but these things are hard to see in 1 one-colour plot...

```
# Define Sequences for Multivariate Function
xf3x1 <- seq(-100, 100, length=500)
xf3x2 <- seq(-100, 100, length=500)

# Outer Calculates the Cartesian Product
z <- outer(xf3x1,xf3x2,function(xf3x1,xf3x2) xf3x1*xf3x2)
persp(xf3x1,xf3x2,z,col="lightgreen",theta=30,phi=20, main="Problème 3: Function 3")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plot3D` package is an additional option. `persp3D` colors by z-value by default:

```
library(plot3D)  # For persp3D function

# Define Sequences for Multivariate Function
#### length=50 to speed up plotting ####
xf3x1 <- seq(-100, 100, length=50)
xf3x2 <- seq(-100, 100, length=50)

# Outer Calculates the Cartesian Product
z <- outer(xf3x1,xf3x2,function(xf3x1,xf3x2) xf3x1*xf3x2)

persp(xf3x1,xf3x2, z, theta=30, phi=20, 
      col="lightgreen",
      main="persp: Black border lines overwhelm plot")

persp(xf3x1,xf3x2, z, theta=30, phi=20, 
      col="lightgreen",
      border="black", lwd=0.2,  # Or border=NA per @jlhoward
      main="persp: Thinner border lines")

persp3D(xf3x1,xf3x2, z, theta=30, phi=20, 
        main="persp3D: No borders by default")

persp3D(xf3x1,xf3x2, z, theta=30, phi=20, 
        border="black", lwd=0.5,
        main="persp3D with borders")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to set `border=NA` to turn off the borders around the surface facets.

One way is to color based on z-value. Adapting [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357002/create-3d-plot-colored-according-to-the-z-axis):

```
nrz <- nrow(z)
ncz <- ncol(z)
color <- rev(rainbow(100))
zfacet <- z[-1, -1] + z[-1, -ncz] + z[-nrz, -1] + z[-nrz, -ncz]
facetcol <- cut(zfacet, 100)
persp(xf3x1,xf3x2,z,col=color[facetcol],border=NA,,theta=30,phi=20)
```

[image]

I'd encourage you to try `surface3d(...)` in the `rgl` package, which creates rotatable 3D plots. The image below is just a screen shot.

```
zlen <- diff(range(z)) + 1
clrs <- rev(rainbow(zlen))
col <- clrs[ z - min(z) + 1 ] # assign colors to heights for each point
open3d(scale=c(100,100,1))
surface3d(xf3x1,xf3x2,z,col=col, main="Problème 3: Function 3")
axes3d(box=TRUE)
title3d(xlab="xf3f1", ylab="xf3x2", zlab="z")
```

[image]