# How to colour 3D graph (persp) when I have 3 explanatory variables?

Tags: r, plot, 3d, interaction

How do I colour a 3D graph I've done using `persp`?

please use this data to reacreate the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vay1e86tdtclrf1/data.xlsx?dl=0

The code shown in this link doesn't work for me because I have 3 explanatory variables and 2 interactions: [Create 3D Plot Colored According to the Z-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357002/create-3d-plot-colored-according-to-the-z-axis)

I got all kind of errors when I tried to adapt it to my case. How to use outer in my case? or to get  `zfacet = z1[-1, -1] + z1[-1, -ncz] + z1[-nrz, -1] + z1[-nrz, -ncz]`

For example:

```
Error in seq.int(rx[1L], rx[2L], length.out = nb) : 'from' must be finite
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

This link uses a function, but I don't really understand it: http://pj.freefaculty.org/guides/Rcourse/plot-3d/plots-3d.pdf

rv is my dependent variable
x, y, y2 are my explanatory variables (please note that y2 is just y^2)
then my model is rv~x*y+y2+x:y2

My code to plot the 3D graph looks like this

```
    library(akima)

x <- data$x
y <- data$y
y2 <- y^2
z <- data$rv
m <- glm(rv ~ x*y+y2+x:y2, family=gaussian)

i <- 5
xtemp <- seq(min(x),max(x),length.out=i)
xrange <- rep(xtemp,times=i) 
ytemp <- seq(min(y),max(y),length.out=i)
yrange <- rep(ytemp,each=i) 
y2temp <- seq(min(y),max(y),length.out=i)
y2range <- rep(ytemp,each=i) 
newdata <- data.frame(x=xrange,y=yrange,y2=y2range)

zhat <- predict(m,newdata=newdata,type=c("response")) 

xyz <- interp(xrange,yrange,that)

quartz()
persp(xyz,theta = 35, phi = 50,col="white", border="grey40", ticktype = "detailed", zlim=c(1,7)) -> res2
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Where are `that` and `m` defined?

Comment: thank you, I just added that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the logic of the function in the link:

```
jet.colors <- colorRampPalette( c("#ffcccc", "#cc0000") )
nbcol <- 100
color <- jet.colors(nbcol)
nrz <- length(xyz[[1]])
ncz <- length(xyz[[2]])
z<-xyz[[3]]
zfacet <- z[-1, -1] + z[-1, -ncz] + z[-nrz, -1] + z[-nrz, -ncz]
facetcol <- cut(zfacet, nbcol)

persp(xyz,theta = 35, phi = 50,col=color[facetcol], border="grey40", ticktype = "detailed", zlim=c(1,7))
```