# colorful plot using persp

Tags: r, plot, colors, 3d

I am using ´persp´ to generate 3D-Plot. it is the result:

```
persp(TestMatrix ,theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.19,scale=FALSE,shade=0.4,border=NA,box=FALSE)
```

[image]

in my diagram. I would like to change the color continuous from blue to red.

what should I do?

**UPDATE**

I would like generate a diagram like this:
[image]

Comment: Just build a contour plot. These are usually a much better visualization then perspective plots (in particular if the viewer can't change the perspective).

Comment: Do you have anexample for me?

Comment: See the examples in `help("filled.contour")`.

Answer (score 7):

If you just need a shaded red curve, try to add a `col`parameter in your persp function :

```
persp(TestMatrix, 
      theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.19, scale=FALSE,
      shade=0.4, col="red", border="blue",
      box=FALSE)
```

[image: Graph using ?persp exemple datas]

***Edit :***
Thanks for your edit, I wasn't sure you needed a two-colors plot. There is an question on this problem here : [Create 3D Plot Colored According to the Z-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357002/create-3d-plot-colored-according-to-the-z-axis?rq=1). You need a color matrix to specify the colors of each facet of the surface. The subtil point is to calculate the height (z) in the middle of each facet, ie the mean of the four summit of the grid (which correspond to z values).
Adapting the answer for your graph, the solution can be something like that :

```
# Color palette (100 colors)
col.pal<-colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red"))
colors<-col.pal(100)
# height of facets
z.facet.center <- (z[-1, -1] + z[-1, -ncol(z)] + z[-nrow(z), -1] + z[-nrow(z), -ncol(z)])/4
# Range of the facet center on a 100-scale (number of colors)
z.facet.range<-cut(z.facet.center, 100)

persp(x, y, z, 
  theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.19, scale=FALSE,
  shade=NA, col=colors[z.facet.range], border="grey80",
  box=FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Decoupling the palette creation part, we can implement a 3D plotting function `plot.3d()` which accepts the `pal.func` as argument:

```
plot.3d <- function(x, y, z, pal.func, nlevels=50) {
  colors <- pal_func(nlevels)
  z.facet.center <- (z[-1, -1] + z[-1, -ncol(z)] + z[-nrow(z), -1] + z[-nrow(z), -ncol(z)])/4
  z.facet.range <- cut(z.facet.center, nlevels)
  persp(x, y, z, theta = 30, phi = 45, scale=FALSE,
        expand = 0.2, col=colors[z.facet.range], box=FALSE)
} 

x <- seq(-3,3,0.15)
y <- seq(-3,3,0.15)
s <- 1
z <- outer(x, y, function(x,y) 50/s^4/pi*(1-(x^2+y^2)/2/s^2)*exp(-(x^2+y^2)/2/s^2))

plot.3d(x, y, z, pal.func = colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red")))
```

[image]

using the library `GA` we can get `maltlab` like  `jet` colormap

```
library(GA)
plot.3d(x, y, z, pal_func=jet.colors)
```

[image]