# BRT: Add gradient colors to interaction plots using gbm.perspec

Tags: r, machine-learning, tree, gbm, dismo

I would like to add a gradient of colours following the fitted values (e.g. higher fitted values darker colours, lower fitted values lighter colours) in my three-dimensional dependence plots.

I have used the example presented in dismo package:

```
library(dismo) 
data(Anguilla_train)
angaus.tc5.lr01 <- gbm.step(data=Anguilla_train, gbm.x = 3:13, gbm.y = 2,
family = "bernoulli", tree.complexity = 5, learning.rate = 0.01, 
bag.fraction = 0.5)

# Find interactions in the gbm model:
find.int <- gbm.interactions( angaus.tc5.lr01)
find.int$interactions
find.int$rank.list
```

I have only managed to add the same colour to the whole plot:

```
gbm.perspec( angaus.tc5.lr01, 7, 1,
            x.label = "USRainDays",
            y.label = "SegSumT", 
            z.label = "Fitted values",
            z.range=c(0,0.435),
            col="blue")
```

[image: Interaction plot all in one colour]

Or to add a gradient colour but not following the fitted values:

```
    gbm.perspec( angaus.tc5.lr01, 7, 1,
             x.label = "USRainDays",
             y.label = "SegSumT", 
             z.label = "Fitted values",
             col=heat.colors(50),
             z.range=c(0,0.435))
```

[image: Interaction plot with different colours not following fitted values]

I also checked the code of function gbm.perspec, and If I understood correctly the fitted values are call inside the formula as "prediction", and later on are part of the "pred.matrix" that is passed to the final plotting: persp(x = x.var, y = y.var, z = pred.matrix...), but I have no managed to access them from the gbm.perspec formula. I tried to modified the gbm.perpec function by adding "col=heat.colors(100)[round(pred.matrix*100, 0)]" into the persp() inside the function, but it does not do what I am looking for:

```
persp(x = x.var, y = y.var, z = pred.matrix, zlim = z.range, 
      xlab = x.label, ylab = y.label, zlab = z.label, 
      theta = theta, phi = phi, r = sqrt(10), d = 3, 
      ticktype = ticktype,
      col=heat.colors(100)[round(pred.matrix*100, 0)], 
      mgp = c(4, 1, 0), ...)
```

[image: Interaction plot coloured following predicted values (?) but not showing the colours properly]

I believe the solution might come from modifying the gbm.perpec function, do you know how?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By incorporating some of the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39117827/colorful-plot-using-persp) into the `gbm.perspec()` source code you can create the desired effect.

First run

```
# Color palette (100 colors)
col.pal<-colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red"))
colors<-col.pal(100)
```

Then, add `z.facet.center` to `gbm.perspec()` source code after `else` and change the `z` in the code to `pred.matrix`as follows,

```
# and finally plot the result
#
if (!perspective) {
  image(x = x.var, y = y.var, z = pred.matrix, zlim = z.range)
} else {
  z.facet.center <- (pred.matrix[-1, -1] + pred.matrix[-1, -ncol(pred.matrix)] + 
                       pred.matrix[-nrow(pred.matrix), -1] + pred.matrix[-nrow(pred.matrix), -ncol(pred.matrix)])/4
  # Range of the facet center on a 100-scale (number of colors)
  z.facet.range<-cut(z.facet.center, 100)
  persp(x=x.var, y=y.var, z=pred.matrix, zlim= z.range,      # input vars
        xlab = x.label, ylab = y.label, zlab = z.label,   # labels
        theta=theta, phi=phi, r = sqrt(10), d = 3,
        col=colors[z.facet.range],# viewing pars
        ticktype = ticktype, mgp = c(4,1,0), ...) #
```

which will give you a plot like this (please note, this is not plotted using the sample dataset which is why the interaction effect is different than the plot in the question). [image]

Alternatively, you can create a new function. The following example modifies `gbm.perspec()` to give a white-to-red gradient. Simply run the code in R, then change `gbm.perspec()` to `gbm.perspec2()`

```
# interaction function 

# Color palette (100 colors)
col.pal<-colorRampPalette(c("white", "pink", "red"))
colors<-col.pal(100)

gbm.perspec2 <- function(gbm.object, 
                        x = 1,                # the first variable to be plotted
                        y = 2,                # the second variable to be plotted
                        pred.means = NULL,    # allows specification of values for other variables
                        x.label = NULL,       # allows manual specification of the x label
                        x.range = NULL,       # manual range specification for the x variable
                        y.label = NULL,       # and y la seminar committeebel
                        z.label = "fitted value", #default z label
                        y.range = NULL,       # and the y
                        z.range = NULL,       # allows control of the vertical axis
                        leg.coords = NULL,  #can specify coords (x, y) for legend
                        ticktype = "detailed",# specifiy detailed types - otherwise "simple"
                        theta = 55,           # rotation 
                        phi=40,               # and elevation 
                        smooth = "none",      # controls smoothing of the predicted surface
                        mask = FALSE,         # controls masking using a sample intensity model
                        perspective = TRUE,   # controls whether a contour or perspective plot is drawn
                        ...)                  # allows the passing of additional arguments to plotting routine
# useful options include shade, ltheta, lphi for controlling illumination
# and cex for controlling text size - cex.axis and cex.lab have no effect
{
  
  if (! requireNamespace('gbm') ) { stop('you need to install the gbm package to use this function') }
  requireNamespace('splines')
  #get the boosting model details
  
  gbm.call <- gbm.object$gbm.call
  gbm.x <- gbm.call$gbm.x
  n.preds <- length(gbm.x)
  gbm.y <- gbm.call$gbm.y
  pred.names <- gbm.call$predictor.names
  family = gbm.call$family
  
  # and now set up range variables for the x and y preds
  
  have.factor <- FALSE
  
  x.name <- gbm.call$predictor.names[x]
  if (is.null(x.label)) {
    x.label <- gbm.call$predictor.names[x]
  }    
  y.name <- gbm.call$predictor.names[y]
  if (is.null(y.label)) {
    y.label <- gbm.call$predictor.names[y]
  }
  data <- gbm.call$dataframe[ , gbm.x, drop=FALSE]  
  n.trees <- gbm.call$best.trees
  
  # if marginal variable is a vector then create intervals along the range
  
  if (is.vector(data[,x])) {
    if (is.null(x.range)) {
      x.var <- seq(min(data[,x],na.rm=T),max(data[,x],na.rm=T),length = 50)
    } else {
      x.var <- seq(x.range[1],x.range[2],length = 50) 
    }
  } else {
    x.var <- names(table(data[,x]))
    have.factor <- TRUE
  }
  if (is.vector(data[,y])) {
    if (is.null(y.range)) {
      y.var <- seq(min(data[,y],na.rm=T),max(data[,y],na.rm=T),length = 50)
    }  else {y.var <- seq(y.range[1],y.range[2],length = 50)}
  } else {
    y.var <- names(table(data[,y]))
    if (have.factor) {  #check that we don't already have a factor 
      stop("at least one marginal predictor must be a vector!")
    } else {have.factor <- TRUE}
  }
  pred.frame <- expand.grid(list(x.var,y.var))
  names(pred.frame) <- c(x.name,y.name)
  pred.rows <- nrow(pred.frame)
  
  #make sure that the factor variable comes first
  
  if (have.factor) {
    if (is.factor(pred.frame[,2])) {  # swap them about
      pred.frame <- pred.frame[,c(2,1)]
      x.var <- y.var
    }
  }
  
  j <- 3
  # cycle through the predictors
  # if a non-target variable find the mean
  for (i in 1:n.preds) {
    if (i != x & i != y) {
      if (is.vector(data[,i])) {
        m <- match(pred.names[i],names(pred.means))
        if (is.na(m)) {
          pred.frame[,j] <- mean(data[,i],na.rm=T)
        } else pred.frame[,j] <- pred.means[m]
      }
      if (is.factor(data[,i])) {
        m <- match(pred.names[i],names(pred.means))
        temp.table <- table(data[,i])
        if (is.na(m)) {
          pred.frame[,j] <- rep(names(temp.table)[2],pred.rows)
        } else {
          pred.frame[,j] <- pred.means[m]
        }
        pred.frame[,j] <- factor(pred.frame[,j],levels=names(temp.table))
      }
      names(pred.frame)[j] <- pred.names[i]
      j <- j + 1
    }
  }
  
  #
  # form the prediction
  #
  #assign("pred.frame", pred.frame, pos=1)
  prediction <- gbm::predict.gbm(gbm.object,pred.frame,n.trees = n.trees, type="response")
  #assign("prediction", prediction, pos=1, immediate =T)
  
  # model smooth if required
  
  if (smooth == "model") {
    pred.glm <- glm(prediction ~ ns(pred.frame[,1], df = 8) * ns(pred.frame[,2], df = 8), data=pred.frame,family=poisson)
    prediction <- fitted(pred.glm)
  }
  
  # report the maximum value and set up realistic ranges for z
  
  max.pred <- max(prediction)
  message("maximum value = ",round(max.pred,2),"\n")
  
  if (is.null(z.range)) {
    if (family == "bernoulli") {
      z.range <- c(0,1)
    } else if (family == "poisson") {
      z.range <- c(0,max.pred * 1.1)
    } else {
      z.min <- min(data[,y],na.rm=T)
      z.max <- max(data[,y],na.rm=T)
      z.delta <- z.max - z.min
      z.range <- c(z.min - (1.1 * z.delta), z.max + (1.1 * z.delta))
    }
  }
  
  # now process assuming both x and y are vectors
  
  if (have.factor == FALSE) {
    
    # form the matrix
    
    pred.matrix <- matrix(prediction,ncol=50,nrow=50)
    
    # kernel smooth if required
    
    if (smooth == "average") {  #apply a 3 x 3 smoothing average
      pred.matrix.smooth <- pred.matrix
      for (i in 2:49) {
        for (j in 2:49) {
          pred.matrix.smooth[i,j] <- mean(pred.matrix[c((i-1):(i+1)),c((j-1):(j+1))])
        }
      }
      pred.matrix <- pred.matrix.smooth
    }
    
    # mask out values inside hyper-rectangle but outside of sample space
    
    if (mask) {
      mask.trees <- gbm.object$gbm.call$best.trees
      point.prob <- gbm::predict.gbm(gbm.object[[1]],pred.frame, n.trees = mask.trees, type="response")
      point.prob <- matrix(point.prob,ncol=50,nrow=50)
      pred.matrix[point.prob < 0.5] <- 0.0
    }
    #
    # and finally plot the result
    #
    if (!perspective) {
      image(x = x.var, y = y.var, z = pred.matrix, zlim = z.range)
    } else {
      z.facet.center <- (pred.matrix[-1, -1] + pred.matrix[-1, -ncol(pred.matrix)] + 
                           pred.matrix[-nrow(pred.matrix), -1] + pred.matrix[-nrow(pred.matrix), -ncol(pred.matrix)])/4
      # Range of the facet center on a 100-scale (number of colors)
      z.facet.range<-cut(z.facet.center, 100)
      persp(x=x.var, y=y.var, z=pred.matrix, zlim= z.range,      # input vars
            xlab = x.label, ylab = y.label, zlab = z.label,   # labels
            theta=theta, phi=phi, r = sqrt(10), d = 3,
            col=colors[z.facet.range],# viewing pars
            ticktype = ticktype, mgp = c(4,1,0), ...) #
    }
  }
  if (have.factor) {
    # we need to plot values of y for each x
    factor.list <- names(table(pred.frame[,1]))
    n <- 1
    #add this bit so z.range still works as expected:
    if (is.null(z.range)) {
      vert.limits <- c(0, max.pred * 1.1)
    } else {
      vert.limits <- z.range
    }
    
    plot(pred.frame[pred.frame[,1]==factor.list[1],2],
         prediction[pred.frame[,1]==factor.list[1]],
         type = 'l', 
         #ylim = c(0, max.pred * 1.1), 
         ylim = vert.limits,
         xlab = y.label,
         ylab = z.label, ...)
    for (i in 2:length(factor.list)) { 
      #factor.level in factor.list) {
      factor.level <- factor.list[i]
      lines(pred.frame[pred.frame[,1]==factor.level,2],
            prediction[pred.frame[,1]==factor.level], lty = i)
    }
    
    # now draw a legend
    if(is.null(leg.coords)){
      x.max <- max(pred.frame[,2])
      x.min <- min(pred.frame[,2])
      x.range <- x.max - x.min
      x.pos <- c(x.min + (0.02 * x.range),x.min + (0.3 * x.range))
      
      y.max <- max(prediction)
      y.min <- min(prediction)
      y.range <- y.max - y.min
      y.pos <- c(y.min + (0.8 * y.range),y.min + (0.95 * y.range))
      legend(x = x.pos, y = y.pos, factor.list, lty = c(1:length(factor.list)), bty = "n")
    } else {
      legend(x = leg.coords[1], y = leg.coords[2], factor.list, lty = c(1:length(factor.list)), bty = "n", ncol = 2)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the gbm.perspec function is certainly an option, although if you use the predicted values from the gbm model and plot them onto a 3D scatterplot from another package you should be able to achieve it as well.

Here's an option using the plot3Drgl package, original code was provided by @Fabrice.

```
library(dismo); library(plot3Drgl); library(devEMF)
data(Anguilla_train)
angaus.tc5.lr01 <- gbm.step(data=Anguilla_train, gbm.x = 3:13, gbm.y = 2,
                            family = "bernoulli", tree.complexity = 5, learning.rate = 0.01, 
                            bag.fraction = 0.5)

# Find interactions in the gbm model:
find.int <- gbm.interactions( angaus.tc5.lr01)
find.int$interactions
find.int$rank.list

d<-plot(angaus.tc5.lr01,c(1,7),return.grid=T)


x <- d$SegSumT
y <- d$USRainDays
z <- d$y


grid.lines = 30
elevation.site = loess(z ~ x*y, data=d, span=1, normalize = FALSE) 
x.pred <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = grid.lines) # x grid
y.pred <- seq(min(y), max(y), length.out = grid.lines) # y grid
xy <- expand.grid( x = x.pred, y = y.pred)  # final grid combined
z.site=matrix(predict(elevation.site, newdata = xy), nrow = grid.lines, ncol = grid.lines) # predicedt matrix

scatter3D(x, y, z, theta = 160, phi = 35, # x y z coords and angle of plot
          clab = c(""), # Needs moving - label legend
          colkey = list(side = 4, length = 0.65, 
                        adj.clab = 0.15, dist = -0.15, cex.clab = 0.6, cex.axis = 0.6), # change the location and length of legend, change position of label and legend
          clim = c(-4,0.1),
          bty = "b", # type of box
          col = ramp.col(col = c("grey", "blue"), 200),
          pch = 19, cex = 0.55, # shape and size of points
          xlab = "SegSumT", 
          xlim=c(10,20),ylim=c(0,3.5), zlim=c(-4,0.1), d= 2,
          ylab = "USRaindays",
          zlab= "Fitted values", #axes labels
          cex.lab = 0.8, font.lab = 1, cex.axis = 0.6, font.axis= 1, # size and font of axes and ticks
          ticktype = "detailed", nticks = 5, # ticks and numer of ticks
          #type = "h", # vertical lines
          surf = list(x = x.pred, y = y.pred, z = z.site,  
                      facets = NA, CI=NULL))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go5W8.png)

By tweaking with grid.lines and reversing the x axis you should be able to produce exactly what you want.