# R: Centre colour scale around specific value in surface plot

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I am making 3D surface plots in R using the function `persp`. With help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357002/create-3d-plot-colored-according-to-the-z-axis) and [this thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-March/019516.html) I have made the following reproducible example inspired by the `persp` documentation:

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(RColorBrewer)

# Import and adjust data
data(volcano)
z <- volcano[1:50, 1:50]    # Cut matrix
z <- (z - 100)/10           # Rescale z-values
x <- 10 * (1:nrow(z))       # 10 meter spacing (S to N)
y <- 10 * (1:ncol(z))       # 10 meter spacing (E to W)

# Create a function interpolating colors in the range of specified colors
jet.colors <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11, "RdBu")))

# Generate the desired number of colors from this palette
nbcol <- 50
color <- jet.colors(nbcol)

# Compute the z-value at the facet centres
zfacet <- z[-1, -1] + z[-1, -ncol(z)] + z[-nrow(z), -1] + z[-nrow(z), -ncol(z)]

# Recode facet z-values into color indices
facetcol <- ntile(zfacet, nbcol)

# Plot
p <- persp(x, y, z, col = color[facetcol], theta = 230, phi = 25, ticktype = 'detailed')
lines(trans3d(c(max(x), max(x), min(x), min(x), max(x)),
              c(max(y), min(y), min(y), max(y), max(y)),
              c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), p),
      col = "blue")
```

[Here is a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrL2i.png) to the resulting 3D plot.

As you can see the colour scale goes from blue to white to red. Currently white is centered around 4.

Suppose I would like the scale to be centered instead around 1 (so that 1 would be white and larger/smaller values would be red/blue), which is shown by the blue line around the box. How can I adjust the value which is represented as white in the scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two possible solutions, one using `persp` (which I am not completely sure is correct) and the other using `rgl::persp3d`.

Both solutions involve sorting the z-values, using two different colour palettes for values below and above the threshold (which is 1 in this example) and finally concatenating the two palettes. In both cases I increased the number of colours significantly to match the number of facets plotted.

### Solution 1: using `persp`

I am not completely sure that this solution is correct because the colours seem slightly off around the threshold. I believe this is because we use the values at the centre of the facets to determine the colours but I could be wrong.

Here is the code and the [resulting graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alN8F.png):

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(RColorBrewer)

# Import and adjust data
data(volcano)
z <- volcano[1:50, 1:50]    # Cut matrix
z <- (z - 100)/10           # Rescale z-values
x <- 10 * (1:nrow(z))       # 10 meter spacing (S to N)
y <- 10 * (1:ncol(z))       # 10 meter spacing (E to W)

# Compute z-values to allocate colors to and generate these colors
# Compute the z-value at the facet centres
zfacet <- z[-1, -1] + z[-1, -ncol(z)] + z[-nrow(z), -1] + z[-nrow(z), -ncol(z)]
# Number of colors which equals number of facets
nbcol <- (dim(z)[1] - 1) * (dim(z)[2] - 1)
# Sort z-values
values <- sort(c(zfacet))
# Number of values below the threshold
length.low <- length(values[values<1])
# Generate colors
color.low <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white"))(length.low)
# Number of values above the threshold
length.high <- length(values[values>=1])
# Generate colors
color.high <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "red"))(length.high)
# Concatenate color vector
color <- c(color.low, color.high)
# Recode facet z-values into color indices
facetcol <- ntile(zfacet, nbcol)

# Plot
p <- persp(x, y, z, col = color[facetcol], theta = 300, phi = 20, ticktype='detailed')
lines(trans3d(c(max(x), max(x), min(x), min(x), max(x)),
              c(max(y), min(y), min(y), max(y), max(y)),
              c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), p),
      col="blue")
```

### Solution 2: using `rgl::persp3d`

A second solution which circumvents this problem is to use `rgl::persp3d`. The procedure is similar but there is no need to worry about facets and the plot seems more or less continuous.

Here is the code (shorter and simpler than the first solution) and the [resulting graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6blsk.png) (which can be rotated freely with a mouse in R):

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(rgl)

# Import and adjust data
data(volcano)
z <- volcano[1:50, 1:50]    # Cut matrix
z <- (z - 100)/10           # Rescale z-values
x <- 10 * (1:nrow(z))       # 10 meter spacing (S to N)
y <- 10 * (1:ncol(z))       # 10 meter spacing (E to W)

# Sort z-values and generate colors for values below and above the threshold
# Sort z-values
values <- sort(c(z))
# Number of values below the threshold
length.low <- length(values[values<1])
# Generate colors
color.low <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white"))(length.low)
# Number of values above the threshold
length.high <- length(values[values>=1])
# Generate colors
color.high <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "red"))(length.high)
# Concatenate color vector
color <- c(color.low, color.high)

# Plot
persp3d(x, y, z, col = color[cut(z, length(z))], lit=FALSE)
```